# Method to make API url

Tags: android, json, api

I have an API with various parameter optional/required. What would be the best way to create a URL for that API

```
syntax: http://www.example.com/type={type}?parameter1={p1,p2}&parameter2={p3}...etc

example: http://www.exmaple.com/type=channels?userid=1234&response=xml&region=india
example http://www.example.com/type=singers?genre=english&length=1&year=2015
```

What's the best approach in `android` to achieve this so that if I pass the type, parameters etc, it return me with the `url`.

Answer (score 0):

In android, better solutions have been created by other developers to help handle http requests. An example would be [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) from Square Inc.

Here is how I would handle this:

- Assuming you know the end-point variations for example: you know the number of possible urls that could be needed (in your question, you have given 2 possibilities), then you can easily create two methods like this:

  ```
  @GET("/{type}/{param1}/{param2}/{otherparam}
  public void fetchXResourcesFromServer(@Path("type") type, @Path("param1") param2, @Path("paramx") otherparam, Callback<ReturnType> cb);

  @GET("/{type}/{genre}/{length}/{year}
  public void fetchYResourcesFromServer(/* see above for remaining part */);
  ```

Now what you could do from here is call the appropriate method depending on which resources you want.

Having an arbitrary number of parameters might be tricky for this case but I am sure there is away you can know ahead of time what data you want to fetch and know the structure of your api first.

Let me know if you have further questions! Good luck!